# How can I only get the boolean value from the return of sysctl, MacOS

Tags: macos, shell, boolean, zsh

I am trying to get the return Boolean value of the command: `sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled`, in a shell script (run with zsh).

This command is for knowing whether macOS enables the limit of speed of low-order tasks (i.e. time machine).

Here is the script I have done now:

```
value=$(sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled)
echo $value
```

The output I got is:

```
>>>debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled: 0
```

But I just want `0`/`1` as output, how can I just get the boolean value but not the whole string? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, to the best of my knowlege, sysctl has no idea of a "boolean" value. The sysctl interface has been invented, before the C language got an ANSI standard and with it the datatype `bool`. Since you are using the shell and the shell also does not have a boolean data type, this should pose no problem anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Reference : https://ss64.com/osx/sysctl.html

With adding `-n` as option, it will only return the value.

e.g.

```
>>>sysctl -n debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled
0
>>>sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=1
>>>sysctl -n debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled
1
```

According to the description, `-n` is for:

> Show only variable values, not their names.  This option is useful for setting shell variables.

And `-b` is for:

> Force the value of the variable(s) to be output in raw, binary format.  No names are printed and no terminating newlines are output.

But I don't know why only `-n` works in this case, `-b` doesn't.

Comment: According to the man-page, `-b` produces the output in binary format, and since the parameter is most likely an integer, it will presumably return for the value `1` a bit pattern where only the rightmost bit is set. You can verify this by trying out a `sysctl -b ... | xxd` and see what you get. You can catch the binary value as well, but then have to convert it in whatever format you want.

Comment: I see. But may I ask, why if I use `sysctl -b debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled` in zsh, it would return nothing to me but not the bit pattern? Such as `00000000000000000000000000000001` if it is 32 bits.

Comment: What did piping into `xxd` show?

Comment: It shows `00000000: 0000 0000 .... `. The terminal didn't show it completely.

Comment: Oh, so, that means raw binary value can only be print out in terminal if I use `| xxd` to convert it?

Comment: `xxd` takes any binary on stdin and converts it to a string containing the hexadecimal representation. See _man xxd_. It is not the only tool doing this. Have a look at, for instance, `od` and `dd`. Human readable data is in form of strings, so whatever output you want to see, the bit pattern produced must be translated into some glyphs, depending on the encoding. This is basically the task of the Terminal application and unrelated to the shell. Seen from the viewpoint of the shell, the **only** known basic dataype to it it is the string.